# Flask change value route returns

Tags: python-3.x, flask, backend

If I have a route:

```
@app.route("/api")
def api():
    return some_val
```

And then `some_val` changes, I need to restart the server for the route to display the new value (I read/write it to a file).
How do I make routes dynamically update their content? Is it even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: How you get `some_val`? Try to calculate it inside of the function `api`

Comment: `some_val` is a list of dicts, and when the user adds one from the frontend, and reloads the page, now each dict is duplicated inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

this might do the trick!

```
import random
@app.route("/api")
def api():
    return str(random.random())
```

or this might be fun! don't forget to install `fortune` in linux!

```
import subprocess
@app.route("/api")
def api():
    return subprocess.check_output('fortune')
```

Comment: Not quite, because I want to return a variable, is there a function that forces the route to reload?

Comment: I guessing mean debug mode `FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run`, when code auto reloads.